# Edit dynamically created button in android

Tags: java, android, service

I am working on an android server-client application. There is a connection between the android application and the server. 
Based on the first message from the server, a number of buttons is created and displayed on the screen. This number usually is between 1 and 10. 
I don't want to initialise 10 buttons in my activity, as maybe, in the future, the number of buttons will increase to 20.

This is the way I initialise buttons and show them on the screen:

```
actionButtons = server.getActionButtons();
TableLayout buttonLayout = 
    (TableLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tblLayoutButtons);

for(int i=0; i< actionButtons.length; i++)
{
    btnAction.setWidth(100);
    btnAction.setHeight(50);
    btnAction.setTag(actionButtons[i]);
    btnAction.setText(actionButtons[i].getName());
    btnAction.setOnClickListener(btnActionClick);
    buttonLayout.addView(btnAction);
}
```

This all works well. But my problem is that the server sends statusupdates for the buttons, every 3 seconds. Each button stands for a light, that can be on or off. A button that is 'ON' should have another background than a button that is 'OFF'. The buttons should be updated every time an update from the server is received.

How could this be done?

Comment: what do you mean by OFF??

Comment: Each button stands for a light, that can be on or off. A button that is 'ON' should have another background than a button that is 'OFF'.

Comment: The networking aspect of this isn't relevant to the actual question. Nothing to do with sockets. Please don't use irrelevant tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make it like this:

```
public void createButtons() {
    actionButtons = server.getActionButtons();
    TableLayout buttonLayout = (TableLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tblLayoutButtons);

    for(int i=0; i< actionButtons.length; i++)
    {
        btnAction.setWidth(100);
        btnAction.setHeight(50);
        btnAction.setTag(actionButtons[i]);
        btnAction.setText(actionButtons[i].getName());
        btnAction.setOnClickListener(btnActionClick);
        btnAction.setId(i);
        buttonLayout.addView(btnAction);
    }
}

public void updateButton() {
    //Get the ID of the button to toggle from the server and get the related view
    ToggleButton buttonToToggle = (ToggleButton) findViewById(Integer.parseInt(server.getMessage()));
    if (buttonToToggle.isChecked()) {
        buttonToToggle.setChecked(false);
        buttonToToggle.setBackground(R.drawable.offImage)
    }
    else {
        buttonToToggle.setChecked(true);
        buttonToToggle.setBackground(R.drawable.onImage)
    }
}
```

This has the advantage, that you just have to send the ID of the Button and it gets toggled.

Alternatively you could send the binary value off all buttons, so you have to send also just a few bytes... In this case, you can assign the buttons their value in a for loop, almost like you create them.

Hope I helped ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change status of an already created Button then while creating them at run time assign them unique Id's using setID(int) method from the View class.

So for your button1 you can,

```
button1.setId(100);
```

and when you want to change thngs you can fetch the ID for the button and change it appropriately.

```
if(toChangeButton.getID() == 100){
   //Change button1
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Good suggestion, but how would I get the 'toChangeButton'? Let's say I've got a method OnUpdateReceived(String status)  that is triggered every time there is a server update. So in this function, the updating should be done, how do I get the 'toChangeButton' in this method?

Comment: How are you determining which status belongs to which button?

Comment: I am assigning an object of 'ActionButton' to the tag of each button. Didn't add that code to question but will add it.
    btnAction.setTag(actionButtons[i]);

Comment: So we can use the getTag method to get the tag and the button for which we wanna make the change like btnAction.getTag(). In this case I guess Id wont be required even.

Comment: To do that, I would need to get all buttons from the activity first. In the OnUpdateReceived method, the actionButton needs to be assigned something first else it will be null. I need to iterate trough all buttons and edit their status

Comment: I am not sure if this can be done without iterating, since you have to update the status for that specific button which was set earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the listview to add the buttons.When you get the data from the server,just update the adapter of the listview.
Hope this helps.

Comment: This maybe would be a solution, but I don't really want to use a listview, as it's no actual list. The buttons should be displayed in a grid in the future in a scrollview.

Comment: Maybe you can create your own adapter then let the listview use it.